# How to apply accelerometer calibrations when the same axis inverted produces a different reading

Tags: accelerometer, robotics, mems

I'm trying to understand the basics of why an accelerometer doesn't produce the same result when orientation upside down, compared to being upright.

For example, my circuit board reads between 9.7-9.85. However, when the same axis is inverted upside down, the value can go between 9-10. I'm trying figure out how you can calibrate an accelerometer if an axis produces more of an acceleration when inverted? Surely this should be the same, except the sign being different?

Understanding basics of why an accelerometer produces a different result when inverted